# Git implementation with nfs share

Tags: git, nfs

I am trying to implement Git in my office. As it is not possible to run apache server on each developer machine, they can't work with clone on their machine. We have a development server with NFS share. I am planing to create git repository and working tree on this NFS share. Git is managed by single user so there will not be any simultaneous push.

My questions are

1. It is a good practice?
2. How can i manage user access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restating here to make sure I am understanding: a shared development "working area", which everyone mounts over NFS and develops on using their browser pointed at the remote apache instance, they work on the same set of files and execute git commands against the same git working copy. If I'm correct in my understanding so far, that does not sound like a good idea.

I would recommend you give each developer their own working area on the apache server, and also their own VirtualHost so they can see their independent files. Now they are able to work independently from other developers. Each of those sets of files would be a git clone of the same repository (probably a bare repository somewhere). This allows for a much saner development workflow for each developer, and there is no risk of developers trampling each other and committing other's code, etc.

User access, you can control this via who is allowed to mount the NFS share.

Comment: That's indeed the way to go. Every developer needs his own working area on the server so he can test his code without committing or sharing it with others - and of course without interfering with other people.

Comment: Each developer will have their own branch. In this case how a developer can run a git commands? Do i need to provide ssh access to each developer? Or is it possible to run by specifying branch path in  NFS share. If command can be run by specifying NFS path, will git log the user who is doing a commit or some other operations?

Comment: Working in a branch still requires a working area, and if they have separate ones, then they can commit to a branch if they want at that point. What do you mean by branch path?

Answer (score 1):

git works over NFS, yes, but it's very slow compared to a local disk.

Having several developers working on the same checked out repo is a recipe for trouble.

I'd set up an "upstream" master repo on a server which developers push and pull from, and then each developer clones the master repo locally on his/her own workstation and works against that.

Comment: Calling it "very slow" doens't even begin to describe it. Glacial might be a better adjective, or perhaps "measured using a geological time scale."

Answer (score 1):

You are defeating the very purpose of git i.e distributed development. I'd recommend you set up something like [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) on a central server that holds the 'official' repository. Developers can clone off of this repository in and work in their local areas. They can then push (well tested) changes to the offical repository. With gitolite you can have fine-grained access controls and several other management tools. Your build and deployment processes should be set up so that only changes from the official repository can be pushed into production.